# How to pass two authorization headers to curl POST request

Tags: rest, authentication, curl, http-headers, authorization

I'm accessing a rest api.
I have to do POST. The webservice is hosted behind the basic authentication. 
To access the given endpoint I have to also send an authorization header.

case 1: 
curl GET http://username:password@example.com/endpoint1 => works

case 2: 
curl GET http://@example.com/endpoint1 -H "Authorization: Basic base64_encode(username:password)" => works

case 3: 
curl POST http://@example.com/endpoint2 -H "Authorization: Basic base64_encode(username:password), Basic another_auth_token" => does not work

case 4: 
curl POST http://username:password@example.com/endpoint2 -H "Authorization: Basic another_auth_token" => does not work

Also tried using php curl curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  'username:password') and it didn't work.

Tried adding headers, Content-Type: application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded and it didn't work.

I need curl POST with the two authorization headers to work.

Any pointers what could be missing?

Comment: what is error you are getting? are you sure you have to post two headers? 
or pass the second set of details in the body of the POST?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass '-H Authorization' twice:

```
curl -X POST http://example.com/endpoint2 \
    -H "Authorization: Basic base64_encode_username_colo_password" \
    -H "Authorization: Basic another_auth_token"
```

I get:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10101
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic base64_encode_username_colo_password
Authorization: Basic another_auth_token
```

Keep in mind, though, that the server (and downstream servers as well) has to be able to deal with multiple authorization headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    curl -X POST
'https://api.amazon / shopify or "your URL"/'
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' // or/AND your USER KEY and PASS in Base 64
-H 'Accept: application/json'
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

for body parameter in CURL You should use -d'{your body in json}after the last Header param.(-H)